# Trying to refetchOnWindowFocus in react native using @tanstack/react-query

Tags: react-native, expo, react-query

Trying to refetchOnWindowFocus in react native using @tanstack/react-query.
I already set the refetchOnWindowFocus to true and it's not refecting the query on the screen visit.

Comment: have you seen the docs about react-native ? https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/react-native#refetch-on-app-focus